# Query error after OR in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with query to base, problem appears after `OR`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in

Here is the code:

```
   $chat2=mysql_query('SELECT * from chat where 
    user1!="" OR  user2!=""  AND status="oczekuje" AND user1="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" 
OR  user2="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"  ');  or die();

 $dodaj2=mysql_fetch_array($chat2);
 $ilosc2=mysql_num_rows($chat2);
```

Here screen from sublime: http://scr.hu/47nh/haujn

Why "OR" is not on red color like `AND`?

Comment: Because you have a semi-colon (;) before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, `or die();` is a separate statement because there is a `;` right before it. You should change to

```
   $chat2=mysql_query('SELECT * from chat where 
       user1!="" OR  user2!=""  AND status="oczekuje" AND user1="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" 
       OR  user2="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"  ') or die();
```

Furthermore, you want to consider:

1. use mysqli_* or PDO to prevent SQL injection attacks
2. add some parentheses to the query. How can you know that MySQL evaluates AND and OR in the same way as intended?

To elaborate point 2, AND takes precedence over OR, so it is evaluated as

```
user1!="" OR
(user2!="" AND status="oczekuje" AND user1="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") OR 
user2="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"
```

Comment: Ok i try Pdo or mysqli thanks.